# C# question about a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, average

In the code below i am calling the extension method [average] 3 times.
First with a lambda, then by an anonymous method and third via a delegate.

The way with the delegate doesn't work. Can somebody explain me why?

Many thans in advance !

-----------CODE-------------

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
            new Person { FirstName = "William", LastName = "Schokkele", Age = 35 },
            new Person { FirstName = "Bill",    LastName = "Gates", Age = 50 },
            new Person { FirstName = "Hanne",   LastName = "Schokkele", Age = 7 }
        };

        Person myPerson = new Person { FirstName = "Hanne", LastName = "Schokkele", Age = 7 };
        myDelegate myDel = new myDelegate(myPerson.GetAge);

        double averageAge= people.Average(p => p.Age);
        double averageAge2 = people.Average(delegate(Person p) { return p.Age; });
        double averageAge3 = people.Average(myDel); //THIS LINE DOESNT WORK. ERROR MESSAGE LIST<Person> does not contains a definition for 'average'
    }
}

public delegate int myDelegate(Person p);

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int GetAge(Person p)
    {
        return p.Age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot cast from one type of delegate to another in C#. Since [`IEnumerable<T>.Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548874.aspx) expects a `Func<T, int>`, that is the delegate you need to supply, regardless of the fact that is has the same signature as `myDelegate`.

You can either change this:

```
myDelegate myDel = new myDelegate(myPerson.GetAge);
```

into:

```
Func<Person, int> myDel = new Func<Person, int>(myPerson.GetAge);
```

or simply pass the method as the parameter, which will create the appropriate delegate for you:

```
double averageAge3 = people.Average(myPerson.GetAge);  // this will work
```

Note that making `GetAge` an instance method (vs a static method) **doesn't make sense**, since it returns the age of the object passed as a parameter, instead of the parent (`this`) object.

This becomes obvious when you look at the `myPerson` object, which is instantiated with "dummy" values, just to get access to its `GetAge` method, which doesn't use any of its properties (you could have simply written `double averageAge3 = people.Average(new Person().GetAge);` and nothing would change).

I would recommend either using an anonymous method (preferred), or making your `GetAge` method `static`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload defined of extension method *Average()* that takes an argument of type `myDelegate`.

The one that matches your case is following :

```
public static double Average<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector);
```

You have to use `Func<T,TReturn>` to make it work instead of `myDelegate`.

### Example:

```
Person myPerson = new Person { FirstName = "Hanne", LastName = "Schokkele", Age = 7 };
Func<Person, Int32> myDel = myPerson.GetAge;

double averageAge = people.Average(p => p.Age);
double averageAge2 = people.Average(delegate(Person p) { return p.Age; });
double averageAge3 = people.Average(myDel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `double averageAge3 = myDel.Invoke(myPerson);`
Or how exactly you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

you should mark your delegate static (it has got no instance context)

```
public static int GetAge(Person p)
```

then define

```
myDelegate myDel = Person.GetAge;
```

or call directly

```
double averageAge3 = Person.Average(myPerson.GetAge);
```